# License issue with xml-apis dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Issue:
All dependencies of my project got resolved.
After moving all the project jars to /lib folder and running with Jetty locally I am getting below error.

```
Error:
Internal error (java.io.IOException): Error occurred during processing zip file C:\Users\Dev.User\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar: C:\dev\testProject\testProject-web\target\testProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\license\LICENSE (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.IOException: Error occurred during processing zip file C:\Users\Dev.User\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar: C:\dev\testProject\testProject-web\target\testProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\license\LICENSE (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.instructions.JarBasedArtifactRootDescriptor.processEntries(JarBasedArtifactRootDescriptor.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.instructions.JarBasedArtifactRootDescriptor.copyFromRoot(JarBasedArtifactRootDescriptor.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.IncArtifactBuilder.build(IncArtifactBuilder.java:146)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.IncArtifactBuilder.build(IncArtifactBuilder.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTarget(IncProjectBuilder.java:1211)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1247)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:1066)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:832)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:419)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:183)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:132)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:301)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:132)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:219)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\testProject\testProject-web\target\testProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\license\LICENSE (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.instructions.JarBasedArtifactRootDescriptor$1.process(JarBasedArtifactRootDescriptor.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.instructions.JarBasedArtifactRootDescriptor.processEntries(JarBasedArtifactRootDescriptor.java:58)
    ... 17 more

Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)
```

It is showing that the license could not be found. The dependency itself consisting the license url in it(I have check the pom file it dependency), I have check the url given in  tag mentioned in pom(inside dependency) file and it is working public.

Dependency URL: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01

POM file: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.pom

License url: https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt

Tried:

1. Removing the .m2 folder and maven update.
2. Invalidating cache and restart

Comment: The stacktrace shows that you are still running from within IntelliJ.  also, nothing in Jetty itself references version `1.4.01` of the `xml-apis` jar (jetty 9.x and 10.x uses 1.3.04, and jetty 11.x doesn't use that dep at all).

Comment: Edit your question, and add the output of `mvn dependency:tree` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Jetty issue, it is not involved here.

Jetty also has no dependency on `xml-apis-1.4.01.jar`.

First, fix your build, you are doing something very awkward within it.

Your dependencies should not be unpacked into your webapp's `WEB-INF/classes` directory (which is what is indicated in your stacktrace).

They should merely be copied to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory without an attempt to unpack them.

This should occur before your `${project.basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/` (directory) is packed into `${project.basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.war` (during the `package` phase of maven)

Comment: Thank you so much for your resposne. I was very much wrong at handling the dependencies and build. Now it got resolved, Thanks a lot for directing me towards the solution.